# laravel, printing user who made the application with His name

Tags: laravel-5

Hello guys av been working for two days unluckily.... I have three tables users table, admin table, and applications table, now the user is registered by admin and then He makes an application for bus which is stored, and the admin can be able to see these applications... I want to print the applications each on its own row which av achieved the problem is getting the name of the user who made that application on its corresponding row as they are printed all on one row,,, anyone who has Idea on how to solve this please assist....

**my application model**

```html
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('Martin\Models\User');
}
```

**user model**

```html
  public function applications()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Martin\Models\Application');
  }
```

**my adminApproveController** //where the applications made by user are viewed

```html
      $apps=Application::all();

    return  view('templates.adminApproveApplications',compact('applications'))->with('apps',$apps);
```

**my adminApproveApplications.blade.php**

```html
  <tbody>
                          @foreach($applications as $application)
                          <tr>
                            <td>{{$application->regNumber}}</td>
                            <td>@foreach($apps as $app){{$app->user->group_name}}@endforeach</td>
                            <td>{{$application->destination}}</td>
                            <td>{{$application->daysHired}}</td>
                            <td>{{$application->dateHired}}</td>
                             <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" name="" value="Approve"></td>
                             <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" name="" value="Disapprove"></td>
                          </tr>
                          @endforeach

                        </tbody>
```

**How the application looks on adminApproveApplications**
[image: I want these two to be separated the marked red and blue, how do I loop?]

Comment: am still stack at this question anyone who has a better way of doing it? I realized my usage of foreach loops are the ones which have a mistake... does anyone know how to display them?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @foreach($applications as $application)
<tr>
    <td>{{$application->regNumber}}</td>
    <td>@foreach($apps as $app){{$app->user->group_name}}@endforeach</td> // <= look here !!
    <td>{{$application->destination}}</td>
    <td>{{$application->daysHired}}</td>
    <td>{{$application->dateHired}}</td>
    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" name="" value="Approve"></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" name="" value="Disapprove"></td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

Why are you putting another foreach here ? do you expect one user / row or many with different groups ?

if only one user, remove the foreach.

If you have more, please provide user - group relation

Comment: if it helped please accept the answer so people would know the solution